# how to seprately queryset admin django and rest api by model manger?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter, django-managers

By code below in admin panel query set return only rows that is_deleted is "false" if I want to return all rows. I have one idea but not sure that is bests or does not have a bug.

all models inherit from this model

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_("is Deleted"))
    objects = BaseModelManager()
    ...
```

and I add filter (is_deleted=false) for all query by the below manager(I can not delete this code because all APIs use this code)

```
class BaseModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_deleted=False)
```

for example, a model book is

```
class Book(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ...
```

In the app admin

```
@register(Book)
class BookAdmin(BaseAdminModel):
    list_display = ('title',)
    list_filter = ('is_deleted',)
```

class BaseAdminModel is

```
class BaseAdminModel(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('is_deleted',)
```

**my idea is to change the "base model" and "base admin model" like this**

```
class BaseModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_deleted=False)

class AdminModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().all()

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_("is Deleted"))
    objects = BaseModelManager()
    admin_objects = AdminModelManager()
    ...

class BaseAdminModel(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('is_deleted',)


    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return self.model.admin_objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally would go with your option two solution. So attaching two managers to the model, one for deleted objects the other showing all objects.

```
class Book(BaseModel):
    ...
    objects = BaseModelManger() # provides deleted=False
    all = models.Manager() # provides all results - default django manager
```

Then in your admin you override the `get_queryset` function. This will be the cleanest and simplist solution going forwards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but by this method, I should add a manager for all models(I have many models) and also overwrite ```get_queryset``` for all models registered in the admin. I do not think it is optimal.